# Yarn installs latest version of dependency instead of downloading the one defined in my package.json

Tags: react-native, version, yarnpkg

When I run the command `yarn install`, I get this error:

```
error react-native@0.73.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=18". Got "16.20.2"
error Found incompatible module.
```

The issue is in my package.json where I defined the react-native version to `"react-native":"0.67.5"`.

For info I removed both the package-lock.json and yarn.lock, then reset the cache but didn't work.

I want to be able to install the specified version of react-native in my package.json.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem. I dont have realy solution, but i have temp solution (use nvm for simplification node version control):

- "yarn" with node v18.x
- downgrade node to v16.x
- in yarn.lock, find the section where the version is listed as 0.73.5 (or another latest one that it complains about), it will be called something like:

react-native@*: version "0.73.5" ...

- copy section name "react-native@*" and remove this section
- find section with needed version, it will be called something like:

react-native@0.68.x: version "0.68.x" ...

- rename as:

"react-native@*, react-native@0.68.x:"

in file it look like:

react-native@*, react-native@0.68.x: version "0.68.x" ...

- "yarn" again, this should make it possible to carry out yarn successfully (at least it helped me)